# seeing %20 in UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I am having this weird issue when I see %20 instead of space in the UILabel.I did PO command on the string variable and it appears normal. Following is the code I am using.

```
NSMutableString *userName = [NSMutableString new]; 
[userName setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is your name", self.userData.fullName]];
userNameLabel.text = [userName upperCase];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Result:
Tom%20Willson

Comment: could you show what you got?

Comment: Where did `self.userData.fullName` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like this...

```
NSMutableString *userName = [NSMutableString new]; 
NSString *endcodedString = [self.userData.fullName stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
[userName setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is your name", endcodedString]]; // ------ Change here -----
userNameLabel.text = [userName upperCase];
```

Comment: Could you separate it so it's clear what your doing. Don't make us scroll to see the change ^^. `NSString *encodedString = [self.userData.fullName stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `appendString` method.

```
NSMutableString *userName = [NSMutableString new]; 
[userName appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is your name", self.userData.fullName]];
userNameLabel.text = [userName upperCase];
```

Comment: What is the value of self.userData.fullName?